# How can I send a raw HTTP request in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, http

I am writing a .NET 5 application which sends requests over a TLS connection to some endpoint.

I tried to use HTTPClient, but it didnt work since i need to construct a HTTPRequestMessage before call the Send method.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I need to send the bytes of pre-serialized request above without converting it to an HTTP object.

```
POST /app/test HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 23

{"msg": "test message"}
```

Comment: You want to post a byte array?

Comment: @Magnus yeah, i want to send a raw request as byte array to be interpreted as HTTP request on server-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to send the bytes of pre-serialized request above without converting it to an HTTP object.

This is extremely unusual. `HttpClient` can't be used for this, unless you know of a parser for `HttpRequestMessage`. There may be a library out there that does that, but I don't know of one.

To send a byte array, you'd have to use a lower-level connection like `Socket` or `TcpClient`. And you'll need to do your own TLS negotiation - `SslStream` may help there.